# How to access a network folder in Ubuntu using the terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, mount, network-shares

I am new to Ubuntu(and Linux for that matter) and I am trying to access files using the terminal.  The network folder is on my Desktop, but when I go to the Desktop folder via the terminal, the network folder is not there.

How do I access files on a network folder via the terminal?

Answer (score 18):

First go to:

> /run/user/1000/gvfs/
>
> cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/

In this directory you will find the name and access of the server you connected to. Enter this cd "name of your server"

Now you connected the server from terminal, but before that you need to enter it from the gui

The other way is to use;
sshfs

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/33480/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-samba-location-ive-mounted-in-nautilus-on-the-command-li "/$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs"

Comment: This worked for me on fedora 24.

Comment: Worked for me under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (jammy)

Answer (score 6):

Network locations mounted under GNOME via the GUI are mounted under `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: Is this still true? I can't confirm this is working on Ubuntu Maverick. I have 2 network folders (1 smb, 1 ftp) mounted via nautilus and they do not appear in `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: this is true for me under Ubuntu 12.04 Precise

Comment: under `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`  for me on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @JanusTroelsen /run/user/$UID/gvfs also works on ubuntu 14

Comment: Worked for me under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (jammy)

Answer (score 6):

First, `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

Next, `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/windows/share-name && sudo mount -t cifs //machine-name/share-name /mnt/windows/share-name -o username=your-username,domain=your-domain`

It will then prompt you for a password.

If the machine is not domain joined, just use the machine name in place of the domain.

This worked for me just now.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 14.04, [Ignacio's answer](https://superuser.com/a/137540/164774) doesn't work. In fact is at other location, as told [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/459093).

Answer (score 1):

Use `smbmount`. It mounts a network location to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have stucked and tried several way. none have worked. I found a simple solutions.

Go to the shared folder in Ubuntu. right click inside the empty space of the folder and select "open in terminal". That´s it.

Comment: I like this because all I was trying to do was figure out how the shared drive was referenced in terminal, and this gives me that path - now I can do with it whatever I want!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to go is to use `find` command and search for files on the network location. Found it under: `/home/user/.gvfs`.

Comment: Worked for me. I would have never worked out the path without this method. Linux is so damn awkward at times.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using the answers here above to access their Google Drives, there's a super easy solution without dealing all this.
Some guy built a FUSE filesystem for Google Drive, written in OCaml.

Check the related git here:
https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

It lets you mount your Google Drive on Linux in few steps.
You'll be able to access everything on your drive from the CLI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).